# Heappop and nsmallest from heapq

Tags: python, heapq

I have another heapq question, that I hope I can get some clarity on.

I have a list:

```
rooms = [[0, 2], [0, 3], [9, 0], [0, 4], [0, 1]]
```

The smallest element in this list is correctly identified by nsmallest as:

```
nsmallest(1, rooms)[0]

output:
[0, 1]
```

However when I use heappop to remove the smallest element, it removes [0, 2]:

```
a, b = heappop(rooms)
print([a, b])

output:
[0, 2]
```

However if I sort rooms first, it will pop the correct element. Why do I need to sort rooms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A heap (according to `heapq`) is a list that satisfies the heap property

```
heap[k] <= heap[2*k + 1], for all k>=0 s.t. 2*k + 1 < len(heap)
heap[k] <= heap[2*k + 2], for all k>=0 s.t. 2*k + 2 < len(heap)
```

`nsmallest` takes an arbitrary iterable as an argument, and *constructs* a heap in order to produce its result.

`heappop` takes a pre-made heap as an argument and modifies it, preserving the heap property in the process.

In your example, `rooms` is not a heap, because `rooms[1] == [0, 3]` is not less than `rooms[2*1 + 2] == rooms[4] == [0, 1]`, so `heappop(rooms)` is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3):

`heapq` assumes that the list you are using has the order of a heap. If it does not have the order of a heap, it will show wrong results. So you need to heapify your list first, then try to use `heappop`. Here is the modified version of your code :

```
from heapq import *
rooms = [[0, 2], [0, 3], [9, 0], [0, 4], [0, 1]]
heapify(rooms)
```

the `rooms` will become like :

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [9, 0], [0, 4], [0, 3]]
```

Now if you call `heappop()` you'll see the mentioned result :

```
heappop(rooms)
```

result :

```
[0, 1]
```